# Code runs fine in R but Knit shows an error

Tags: r, dplyr, knitr

I'm having a problem with the following code in an Rmd file, the problem is that if I run the commands in the console, the code runs perfectly fine, and also there is no mistakes in the syntax, I have change several styles but I'm still receiving the same error when I **knit** the file.

```
Raw_Data96_11$EVTYPE <- as.character(Raw_Data96_11$EVTYPE)

List_Events <- count(Raw_Data96_11, vars = "EVTYPE") 

List_Events <- arrange(List_Events,desc(n)) 

List_Events <- mutate(List_Events, percentage = trunc((100*(n/653530))))

Top_10_Events <- List_Events[1:10,2:3]
```

I had to change the syntax for count, when I run the command in the console, I did not had to use vars, but now I cannot run the command **arrange**, this is the error :

Quitting from lines 98-117 (PA_2_Reproducible_Research.Rmd) 
Error in order(List_Events$n) : argument 1 is not a vector
Calls:  ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> arrange -> eval -> eval -> order
Execution halted

I have included the libraries in that chunk but I'm still receiving an error, does anyone know what is going, is it the syntax or what else do I need to do?

Comment: You'll need to provide more code. It is impossible to tell from what you have posted. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Code works interactively but not while knitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62563941/code-works-interactively-but-not-while-knitting)